# How to acquire Automatic code complement with Fortran in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran

[image]

As shown in the screenshot, there are two windows system computers with same settings, they all have wsl and gfortran in Ubuntu 22.04, and also the same Plugins(Modern Fortran, fortran, Fortran Breakpoint Support) in VScode. The problem is one can complete the code block with "name" and "implicit none" when I type "program", but another computer only with "program". Why? How can I get them both to work?

Comment: are the versions of everything on both machines the same? Ex. gfortran, vscode extensions.

Comment: Impossible for everyone else to tell, provided that you mentioned they have the exact same configuration. So, either you can double check and paste here the details of both setups, or create a bug ticket with the vscode software provider.

Answer (score 0):

You only need [Modern Fortran for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fortran-lang.linter-gfortran) and [fortls](https://fortls.fortran-lang.org/) (which you will be prompted to install).

The completions you are want are offered via `fortls` as opposed to the hard-wired code snippets like `program...`, which are offered by the vscode extension.

---

Full disclosure I am the author of those tools.